# SSDs are constantly dying in a new PC

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, ssd, motherboard, bad-sectors

I recently got a new PC and assembled all myself. I'm casually gaming on it about 1 or 2 hours every other day.

The issue is my SSDs are going bad every few days. First disk worked for a few days and now Windows isn't booting (saying no disk or no boot sector) and chkdsk shows ~88Kb in bad sectors. Second one also worked for a few days and Windows crashed on it and refused to reinstall hanging on "copy files" stag. And the third one can't be recognized by the PC at all nor in bios/uefi nor in Windows when booting for usb stick.

It's now 3 SSDs that went bad one after another in one month. I'm guessing the motherboard or a power supply is bad. I'm only using one SATA port to connect the drive. Tried switching between them too.

Hardware:

- ASRock z170 extreme3 motherboard
- 2x256Gb Samsung EVO SSDs and one PNI 256Gb SSD

Any ideas on what can be wrong? Should I return the motherboard? PowerSupply? Not sure what mistake could I do while wiring it all up since there're only two cables for SSD - data and power.

Answer (score 3):

Do you have your PSU connected to an earthed outlet?

The PSU shorts static electricity and interfering currents to earth in some way, but that doesn't happen if your outlet doesn't have an earth connector. The excess currents can creep into your chips, but usually the RAM is the most vounrable. Guess it can get SSD's aswell.

Comment: I have seen something similar with all drives dying and it was linked to power regulation.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly I have never heard of a bad controller causing bad sectors, but it could corrupt data on a drive. I would want to say swap the PSU in this case since you have tried multiple ports. Try the drives in another computer, just to be sure and try a working ssd with a new PSU. I would want to suggest really bad luck, but Samsung EVO's are generally a quality product. Could I ask where you bought them from?